# How can I enrich a Convolutional Neural Network with meta information?

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, keras, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

I would very much like to understand how I can enrich a CNN with provided meta information. As I understand, a CNN 'just' looks at the images and classifies it into objects without looking at possibly existing meta-parameters such as time, weather conditions, etc etc.

To be more precise, I am using a keras CNN with tensorflow in the backend. I have the typical Conv2D and MaxPooling Layers and a fully connected model at the end of the pipeline. It works nicely and gives me a good accuracy. However, I do have additional meta information for each image (the manufacturer of the camera with which the image was taken) that is unused so far.

What is a recommended way to incorporate this meta information into the model? I could not yet come out with a good solution by myself.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

Usually it is done by adding this information in one of the fully connected layer before the prediction. The fully connected layer gives you K features representing your image, you just concatenate them with the additional information you have.

Comment: Thanks! So it means, I have K features representing the image + 1 meta information. This would mean my fully connected layer had K+1 input nodes, one of them being the meta information?

Comment: Yes, exactly, you can even add more information to the K features representing the images.
Just think of the convolutional network "before" the fully connected layers as a mean to extract features of the images. Then in the fully connected layers, these features are used together for the classification.